# Penalties scored by both feet?

Tags: football, trivia, penalty-shot

[Bobby Zamora and Obafemi Martins](http://www.vibe.ng/14-crazy-epl-facts-didnt-know/) have scored with both feet on kicks from the penalty mark in the Premier League. So, I'm interested in knowing, whether there are any players that have done the same thing in other top European leagues.

Note: Doesn't have to be in the same match or within 90 minutes.

In top level football, e.g, [Andreas Brehme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Brehme) Germany’s left-back at the 1986 and 1990 World Cups, took two penalties with both feet in consecutive tournaments. The kick in 1990, with his right foot, was the winning goal in the World Cup final. Here are those penalty kicks:

[image: left foot]
[image: right foot]

Source: [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/babb/11680631/Double-trouble-why-arent-there-more-two-footed-footballers.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from players already mentioned in the question (Zamora, Martins, Brehme), I couldn't find anyone else who scored penalty-kicks with both feet in top level football (let alone in top European leagues).

But, I have something **juicier** for you!

[Simone Verdi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simone_Verdi) has scored **[2 free-kicks in one game with both feet](https://www.football-italia.net/112342/donadoni-bologna-blame)** for Bologna F.C. 1909, in a Serie A match of the 2017/18 season, Bologna 2-3 Crotone.

Here is the left-foot free-kick:

[image: left]

Here is the right-foot one:

[image: right]

Source: [Serie A YouTube video](https://youtu.be/UUlOGgt_xEo?t=1m52s)

Comment: I thought so too after searching for it's answer, so until someone answer otherwise I am accepting this answer. And at this rate you will clear unanswered questions in no time. Thanks for your effort.